# Hudson integration server is not available

Tags: tomcat, hudson

I just tried to install a plugin for hudson under the "Manage" hudson tab. But as  a result Hudson is no longer running.

I get: Oops! Firefox could not connect to hudson:8180

when I try to access:

http://hudson:8180/hudson/

I have tried to run:

/var/lib/tomcat5.5/webapps$ java -jar hudson.war

but that does not help. Any ideas on how to get Hudson back online? Do I need to restart tomcat?

Comment: well none of us can access that, its not a public domain...

Comment: Of course not its only accessible from the local domain. My question was how to restart hudson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting tomcat solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that "hudson" is your host name?  If it is, did you try

```
http://hostname.with.domain.name:8180/hudson
```

Sometimes the simplest items are the ones we overlook when things don't work.

Comment: It only accessible from the local domain. My question was how to restart hudson I don't expect you to be able to access it.

Comment: I didn't ask to access it, I suggested that you attempt to reach your own hudson server with your own fully qualified domain name.  If that fails, check to see if Tomcat is running, as it probably isn't.

Comment: Did try the fully qualified path but that did nothing. But you are right its seems that tomcat is down (cannot access http://localhost/). I have tried to restart it: http://www.ehow.com/how_4787163_start-tomcat-linux.html but don't have root permission :-(

Answer (score 0):

`java -jar hudson.war` will get hudson to run on port 8080, not 8180.

Run `java -jar hudson.war` and then go to http://localhost:8080

Do you see it?

If you are running hudson on Tomcat, and don't have permissions to start Tomcat, you might want to either consider not using Tomcat, or get your sysadmin to look at your system to start Tomcat.